# (node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "0.0.0.0", user "abcdefghi", database abcdefg", SSL off

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, knex.js, heroku-postgres

i'm building a heroku application with postgress but getting above error, "ALSO WHEN DEPLOYED",
i'm using knexjs to connect to database
here is my connection

```
import knex from 'knex'

const database = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
})

const retrieve = async () => {
    let users = await database.select().from('users')
    return users
}

export default retrieve
```

full error

```
2021-02-02T22:31:25.531198+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "0.0.0.0", user "abcdefghi", database abcdefg", SSL off
2021-02-02T22:31:25.531208+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
2021-02-02T22:31:25.531209+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2021-02-02T22:31:25.531211+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2021-02-02T22:31:25.531211+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)
2021-02-02T22:31:25.531212+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2021-02-02T22:31:25.531213+00:00 app[web.1]:     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
2021-02-02T22:31:25.531214+00:00 app[web.1]:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
2021-02-02T22:31:25.531214+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
2021-02-02T22:31:25.531215+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
2021-02-02T22:31:25.531823+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 5)
2021-02-02T22:31:25.532056+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is weird. You aren't trying to _set_ your `DATABASE_URL`, are you?

Comment: it wasn't actually, I changed it with 0.0.0.0